# JavaScript - How to create date from String with Format "2001-08-22 03:04:05.000"?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a String of the Format "2001-08-22 03:04:05.000."

How can I create a date object from it? I've tried Date.parse, but this causes errors.

Comment: Is the last . a typeo? Because that also might by why you're getting an error.

Comment: "2001-08-22 03:04:05.000." is not a format supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) Safari at least will return an invalid date. Manually parse it with a simple function, or use a library.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const newDate = new Date('2001-08-22 03:04:05.000');

console.log(newDate, typeof newDate, newDate.getMonth());

// throws an error
const newDate1 = new Date('2001-08-22 03:04:05.000.');

console.log(newDate1, typeof newDate1, newDate1.getMonth());
```

Just have to place the string in the Date() and you'll have access to it as an object

[Date MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

However if the `2001-08-22 03:04:05.000.` <-- if that period isn't a typo then that might be why you're getting an error.

Edit: Also as the link says `Date.parse()` is discouraged due to browser compatibility.

Comment: Trust the MDN link, parsing unsupported formats (and even some supported ones) is fraught.

Answer (score -2):

```
new Date('2001-08-22 03:04:05.000').getFullYear();
new Date('2001-08-22 03:04:05.000').getMonth();
new Date('2001-08-22 03:04:05.000').getDate();
new Date('2001-08-22 03:04:05.000').getHours();
new Date('2001-08-22 03:04:05.000').getMinutes();
new Date('2001-08-22 03:04:05.000').getSeconds();
```

Comment: Code–only answers aren't helpful. A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it. In Safari (and possibly other implementations), every expression in this answer returns NaN.

Comment: please explain how your code works